# Is the vector $3 + x^2$ in the subspace spanned by $\sin^2 x$ and $\cos^2 x $?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

My idea was: if $3 + x^2$ was  in the subspace spanned by the other two, then it would be some linear combination of those two. So what I did is I formed the Wronskian, found that it was not identically zero everywhere, and concluded that this meant that $3 + x^2$ was not in the span of the other two. I'm actually doubtful that this will work though.

Can someone please explain whether or not this would work, and if it's wrong, please push me in the right direction as to how to approach this question?

Comment: As vectors over what? As vectors over the field of rational or real or complex numbers, no. As vectors over the field of rational functions with rational, real or complex coefficients, yes.

Comment: Whoops, sorry for the omission! The question says as a subspace of all continuous functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems to work, but there are simpler ways to do this : for example, notice that any linear combination of $\cos^2$ and $\sin^2$ is periodic (or bounded), while $3+x^2$ isn't...